# Make a Interface for Pythons Autobahn Framework

Tags: python, autobahnws

I am currently building a client-server-type application with Pythons autobahn (asyncio) framework on both ends. I already have the basic setup of the server, which consists of the server itself and a database managing module. For the client I want to have the networking in a separate module, so I can call `<networkingModule>.sendMessage("msg")` for example. Is that a good way to do it?
My problem however is, the code used to initialize the client doesn't give me a real object to work with.

```
import asyncio

factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)
factory.protocol = <ClientProtocolName>

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_connection(factory, '127.0.0.1', 9000)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

The class itself is:

```
class <ClientProtocolName>(WebSocketClientProtocol):

def onConnect(self, response):
    print("Server connected: {0}".format(response.peer))

def onOpen(self):
    print("WebSocket connection open.")
    self.sendInput()

def _sendMessage(self, msg):
    self.sendMessage(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))

def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    if isBinary:
        print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
    else:
        print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
    print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))
```

So my question is: Is there a way to build a "networking module" so I can access the sendMessage method from outside and would that be a good way to go about this problem, or should I just stuff all my programm logic into the client itself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, your question is attracting close votes, because it doesn't fit within the guidelines for questions here, for a number of reasons.    I suggest that you review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic